# Doubts regarding constrained optimisation using substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a real valued function $f(x,y)$ strictly increasing in both variables, but at a decreasing rate, i.e:
\begin{align}
i=x,y && \frac{\partial f}{\partial i} \geq 0 \land\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial i^2}<0
\end{align}

I intend to maximise it with the constraint:
$$
g = x+by \hspace{2em} \mathrm dg=0
$$
To give context, $f$ is a utility function and the constraint is budget.

My question is what will be the total derivative of $f(g-by,y)$. I have two conflicting answers:
$$
\mathrm df= \frac{\partial f}{\partial(g-by)} \mathrm d(g-by) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy
$$
$$
\mathrm df= -b\frac{\partial f}{\partial(g-by)} \mathrm dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy
$$
Is this correct, and if it is, is there any way to simplify this further, especially getting rid of the first partial term?

The other is by totally differentiating $F(y) = f(g-by,y)$:
\begin{align}
\mathrm dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \mathrm  dy = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathrm  dy
\end{align}

I am fairly certain the latter is wrong, and I am somehow abusing the notation; I am yet to do multivariable calculus with rigour.

My other question is how can I find the general shape of $F(y)$ that is how $f(x,y)$ changes with $y$ when $x$ satisfies the constraint? Intuitively I can tell it's going to be sort of bell shaped (in the positive quadrant), i.e., it will first increase then decrease because of the diminishing returns stated in the first equation. How do I go about showing this formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself since I mostly figured it out. The first total derivative seems correct but there's a nicer way of going about things, which isn't very abusive of notations:
$$
\mathrm df = f_x \mathrm dx + f_y \mathrm dy
$$
From the constraint, $\mathrm dx = -b\mathrm dy$:
$$
\mathrm df = -bf_x|_{x=g-by} \mathrm dy + f_y \mathrm dy
$$
Here, I am substituting the total derivatives instead of the variables, and evaluating the partial derivative at constraint, which feels nicer.

The second answer is wrong probably because we cannot directly substitute $f=F$ in $\partial F/ \partial y$; something to do with how partial derivatives misbehave when treating them as fractions unlike total (usually); I can't really explain it with rigour but once you notice how partial derivatives treat the other variables of a function as constant, you realise how inseparable they are from the original function.

As for the final answer which is the entire reason I am avoiding the Lagrangian:
\begin{gather}
\frac{\mathrm df}{dy} = -bf_x + f_y\\
\frac{\mathrm d^2f}{\mathrm dy^2} = -b\left( f_{xx}\frac{\mathrm dx}{dy} + f_{xy} \right) + f_{yy} + f_{yx} \frac{\mathrm dx}{dy}
\end{gather}

Substituting the total derivatives again will show that the second derivative is always negative assuming the unmentioned Inada condition i.e., cross partial derivatives are positive.